# Let $X,Y,Z$ be independent discrete random variables. Calculate $P(X<Y<Z)$

Tags: probability

Suppose $X,Y,Z$ are independent discrete random variables, how do I calculate $P(X<Y<Z)$? For an example let $X,Y,Z$ be $Pois(\lambda_{1})$, $Pois(\lambda_{2})$ and $Pois(\lambda_{3})$, respectively.

I think the answer is the form of a triple summation, but what are the bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your Poisson example (or any discrete one):

$$
P(X<Y<Z) = \sum_{x<y<z}P(X=x,Y=y,Z=z) = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\sum_{y=x+1}^{\infty}\sum_{z=y+1}^{\infty}P(X=x,Y=y,Z=z)
$$

If you are blessed with independence, then $P(X=x,Y=y,Z=z)$ is easy to calculate at least in the Poisson case. And those scary infinity summations are gonna be easy to deal with by the "everything sum to one" property of Poisson distribution (every distribution indeed), you just have to be careful with the index.